# Как запустить программу

Tags: python, django

В php есть команда `exec`, а есть ли аналог в django? Можно ли запустить из папки static/program.exe?

Comment: Многопоточность нужна при этом?

Comment: да, но пока что только начинаю вникать в эту тему, поэтому сам попробую разобраться, не получится напишу сюда =)

Comment: тогда надо бы использовать что то типа subprocess https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете использовать функцию [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system), которая выполняет произвольную команду в системной оболочке.

***Пример:***

```py
import os

os.system(r'static\program.exe')
```